# Relationships between models (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 2 models **venta and detalleventa**
which is fine since a sale can have many details

```
class Venta(models.Model):
cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Cliente')
fecha =  models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, verbose_name='Detalle del pedido')
total = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, verbose_name='Total de la venta')

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.id)

class DetalleVenta(models.Model):
producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Producto')
cantidad = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Cantidad')
venta = models.ForeignKey(Venta,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Venta')

def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.venta,self.producto)
```

How do I access detail from venta if the foreign key has detalle?
because if there are several detalles you should not edit one by one if you do not edit the venta that contains all the detalles

So far I can edit but through its detalle:

```
class VentaUpdate(UpdateView):
model = DetalleVenta
second_model = Venta
template_name = 'venta/venta_form.html'
form_class = DetalleForm
second_form_class = VentaForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('venta:ventas_listar')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(VentaUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', 0)
    detalle = self.model.objects.get(id=pk)
    venta = self.second_model.objects.get(id=detalle.venta_id)
    if 'form' not in context:
        context['form'] = self.form_class()
    if 'form2' not in context:
        context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(instance=venta)
    context['id'] = pk
    return context

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object
    id_detalle = kwargs['pk']
    detalle = self.model.objects.get(id=id_detalle)
    venta = self.second_model.objects.get(id=detalle.venta_id)
    form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=detalle)
    form2 = self.second_form_class(request.POST, instance=venta)
    if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form2.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

It works, but the idea is to edit a venta and not a detalle

Comment: Why did you use foreignkey? I'm guessing each venta can have only one detalle and each detalle can have only one venta? If so, you can use OneToOneField. Also to be able to reach detalle from venta, you have to use 'related_name' which provides a reverse relation.                            venta = models.ForeignKey(Venta,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Venta', related_name='detalle')

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
Now I can get the detail from the sale model, but I get the following error:

IntegrityError at /venta/nueva
(1048, "Column 'venta_id' cannot be null")

Comment: Please add the details to the question. When did the error happened? Did you update your model?

Comment: If you update it and now it's like this:

venta = models.ForeignKey(Venta,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='detalleventa', verbose_name='Venta')

This error occurs when saving or updating

Comment: A question about what told me that a sale only has one detail, can that detail contain many products with sets formsets? It is right?

Comment: With your current settings, it is the opposite. I'll give you an example for Foreign key and you figure it out. Let's say there are 2 models. Person and Book. Each book can have one owner but a person can have multiple books. So, I have to add a foreign key to the Book.

Comment: By the way, each change in your model classes actually should be also changed in your database. So, if you change a model, don't forget to 'makemigrations' and 'migrate'

Comment: if for that reason the external key is in detalle, since several of them belong to a single venta, but when I want to update a sale through the venta, I have to call the details that refer to that venta and not a detail that is my problem

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your problem. Can you give more detail please?

Comment: If at the time of doing an update I have to access that sale by its primary key and thus bring all its associated details that I could not access because the external key was in detail as well in the question (views) but with the solution that I gave to put related_name = 'detail' If I can recognize the detail of the sale, but I get the error

IntegrityError at / venta / nueva (1048, "Columna 'venta_id' no puede ser nulo")

Comment: Do you have an email to be able to communicate there? comments are very limited

Comment: mcagataybarin@gmail.com